# Error: no match for call to '(Time) (int, int, int)'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am learning C++ and I'm attempting to complete a practice with a header file that is not included in dev c++. I have already tried importing the header file, and dev c++ shows it is listed as a header. Additionally I have created a project and added the ccc_time.h file to the project before compiling per this common question. Here is what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "ccc_time.h"

int main()

{
    Time wake_up;

    wake_up (7, 7, 7);
    wake_up.add_seconds(1000);
    cout << wake_up.get_hours()
        << ":" << wake_up.get_minutes()
        << ":" << wake_up.get_seconds() << "\n";

    Time now;
    int seconds_left = Time(23, 59, 59).seconds_from(now);

    cout << "There are "
    << seconds_left
    << " seconds left in this day.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

`[Error] no match for call to '(Time) (int, int, int)'`

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show the definition of Time class (header)

Comment: This line looks strange -int seconds_left = Time(23, 59, 59).seconds_from(now);   Shouldn't you be calling a method on an object, not a constructor?

Comment: We have no idea what `ccc_time.h` looks like.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling the constructor `Time(int, int, int)` you should do:

```
Time wake_up (7, 7, 7);
```

If not `Time` should have `operator(int, int, int)`.

Edit: You can define `operator(int, int, int)` as follows:

```
void Time::operator(int a, int b, int c)
{
  // do something appropriate
}
```

Comment: Thank you,but I had already tried that and it didn't help. I believe it is a problem with dev c++ recognizing the header file. Because I decided to add the header file into the scritp first and it executes properly. So there is either an issue with the header file, me calling on it, or dev c++.

Comment: how to make operator(int,int,int).

Comment: Added operator definition example